# knockout.js preventing first value change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've a view with knockout.js which has some textboxes and dropdowns.

known when the user changes a value i save the data with a $post

for this i created some computed propties like

```
   self.subjectChanged ko.computed(function () {

        var subject self.subject();
//save...
```

But this also triggers when the subject was loaded from database and set for first time.
What is the best practice for this ?

A similar problem is that i have a function getdata() which depends on two properties.
Now on load this method is raised twice (for each property)

What are best practices to handle this szenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to load the page and bind the data as normal, and then use subscriptions to monitor changes to the observable you are interested in. 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables

```
viewModel.subject.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // code you want to run when the value changes...
});
```

for example http://jsfiddle.net/m8mb5/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best practice, but in the past I tied a loaded variable to the vm and when the data finished loading from the server I set it to true;

In my computeds I would surround the code that actually did the work in an if that checked the loaded.  Computeds can be a little tricky though, you may need to reference the observables outside of the if to ensure they fire correctly.

```
com = ko.computed(function(){
   if(loaded){
      var subject = self.subject();
   }
   // reference observable outside of if to ensure the computed fires when the observable changes
   self.subject();
});
```

Comment: I also thought about this but i get some data via json post. (2 kinds of subitems) so i would need for each an own variable